# How to set Excel cell format as text using JavaScript in browser

Tags: javascript, excel, google-chrome

I'm trying to export a CSV file using javascript in browser, but numbers are shown in abbreviation format when opening with Excel.
**1618088339444340 --> 1.61809E+15**
How can I set excel cell format using JS in browser, no NodeJS please.

Comment: If I paste `1618088339444340` into Excel, it shows scientific notation, unless I double click on the cell. Does this happen with your CSV file or is it always in scientific notation?

Comment: @Samathingamajig yes, it does, the value is correct but shown in scientific notation.

Comment: (excel) CSV files don't include formatting, just data. Re-format the display of them using excel's formatting options.